# Html library for extract text

Tags: html, c, html-parsing

i want to extract the cost of the card from a page like this:

http://magic.tcgplayer.com/db/magic_single_card.asp?cn=Black%20Lotus

What library i have to use for do it in C?
And for download the page?

Comment: Aside from being against their Terms of Service, you really should start with google. You seem to have shown little knowledge about the subject at hand, and this would take major help to get you to the point of completion.

Answer (score 0):

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/htmltidy.html
You should also try to search for 'HTML scraping'.